# What is the best way to use jqgrid where i want to post the entire grid at once?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, grid

I have an asp.net-mvc website and on one page, I have a form (basic CRUD) that shows Order information

Inside an order, you can select many product so inside the form i want to post a table.  I was thinking of using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) for this but i have always done this in the past where on every edit and add, you are posting to the server and refreshing . .

the issue is i can't post any of the product information to the server until i post the overall order so i have an orderId.

Is there anyway i can use jqGrid purely add rows on the client side and then post the whole grid (set of products) as part of the post of my form?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to use the standard [`jQgrid inline editing functionality`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) to edit and/or add rows in-place and then when the user has finished working with the data, construct a JSON object from the table containing all the values and POST them to the server using an AJAX request.

Let's have an example. Suppose we have the following view model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller action which will retrieve a collection of products and return them as JSON array. This controller action will be invoked by jQgrid using an AJAX call when the page is initially loaded in order to retrieve the data:

```
public ActionResult GetProducts()
{
    var products = new[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Product 1" },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Product 2" },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Product 3" },
    };
    return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now inside the view you could have a table and an anchor that will be used to submit to the server all the data:

```
<table id="products"></table>

@Html.ActionLink("Complete order", "CompleteOrder", null, new { id = "completeOrder" })
```

The last peace of the puzzle is of course some javascript to make this alive:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#completeOrder').click(function () {
        var data = $("#products").jqGrid('getRowData');
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(result) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    var lastId;
    $('#products').jqGrid({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetProducts")",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: [ "Id", "Name" ],
        colModel: [
            { name: "Id", width: 55, editable: true },
            { name: "Name", width: 90, editable: true }
        ],
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastId) {
                jQuery('#products').restoreRow(lastId);
                jQuery('#products').editRow(id, true);
                lastId = id;
            }
        },
        editurl: 'clientArray' // <!-- This prevents jQgrid from sending an AJAX request to the server when the client has finished editing a row
    });
</script>
```

Now you could have a server side controller action that will be invoked when the user clicks on the link and which will take all the products:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CompleteOrder(IList<Product> products)
{
    return Json(products);
}
```

Of course this is just an oversimplified example but illustrates the mechanism involved. The jQgrid control has far more possibilities and advanced functionality that you could take advantage of. I would recommend you going carefully through the [`Demos`](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) page on the official website and familiarize yourself with them.